# includeScript gets 401 (Unauthorized) on Force.com site; working fine on Preview of VisualForce Page

Tags: visualforce, force.com, angularjs, include

I am working on an AngularJS SPA app in a developer org. I have the app running fine when I click 'Preview' from the VisualForce Page, but when I put this same page in a Force.com site, I am getting a 401 on an include script.

`<apex:includeScript value="{!$Page.Scripts}" />`

Do I need to do anything special to make this work?

--
Jake

Comment: I presume the issue is that your {!$Page.Scripts} doesn't output the domain and site prefix that are available from the [Site](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) class. You can check that by using "View Source" or "Inspect Element" or in the Developer Tools Network tab. Note that you can write your Angular app so that JavaScript and page partials are served from static resources rather than Visualforce; this speeds development and removes the temptation to mix in server-side `{! }` expressions in what should be cacheable resources.

Comment: See https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/IssuesInGitHub for an example of using static resources.

Comment: Did you include the VF page Page.Scripts in Force.com site "Site Visualforce Pages" section?

Comment: @KeithC, my force.com site is at dev-edition.force.com/example and it's looking for scripts at dev-edition.force.com/example/Scripts.

To give some background, I zipped up my app and loaded it as a static resource. Had the same issue where Preview worked fine, but not as a Site. It had something to do with using Date.now() as a prefix for my resourceURL constant. So I put app.js in a VF script and so I could use URLFOR($Resource.MyApp... instead of Date.now() as discussed [here](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/serving-angularjs-templates-from-static-resources/#comment-3110).

Comment: That URL dev-edition.force.com/example/Scripts looks right to me. Suggest you manually enter some URLs until you hit the page. (Presume the Visualforce saved OK and there is nothing obvious in the Network tab of your Developer Tools.) I have scripts serving fine from zipped static resources in a site named "eep" using URLs like "/eep/resource/1443710372000/cveep__appzip/lib/angular/angular.min.js" produced via `<script src="{!URLFor($Resource.appzip, 'lib/angular/angular.min.js')}"></script>` in my index page that is a Visualforce page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting my entire Angular app in a static resource and referencing it in my main visualforce page. Then, just above the reference to `app.js` in my main visualforce page, I put this code (can't remember the source...):

```
<script>
"use strict";
var serverData = angular.module('serverData', [])
  .constant('resourceUrl', '{!URLFOR($Resource.MYRESOURCE, "app")}'.split('?')[0]);
</script>
```

and added `serverData` as a dependency in my `app.js`. This allowed me to do:

```
.when('/edit/:projectId', {
            templateUrl:  resourceUrl+'/project/project-edit.html'
```